# Confusion with Javascript Ternary Operator in Text Parsing Function

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

I am quite confused with the following snippet found in a `findAndReplace` function:

```
var regex = typeof searchText === 'string' ?
            new RegExp(searchText, 'g') : searchText,
       childNodes = (searchNode || document.body).childNodes,
       cnLength = childNodes.length,
       excludes = 'html,head,style,title,link,meta,script,object,iframe';
```

I thought the ternary operator implied that if the `searchText` is a string, then the regexp object is created. But it also appears that the variables `childNodes`, `cnLength`, and `excludes` are being set irrespective of what type the `searchText` is.

I think I may just be quite confused about the syntax - but are lines 3 through 5 part of the conditional statement or separate? If they are separate, why is there no semicolon at the end of line 2?

Comment: It is just commas; var a=x, b=y, c=z; so `var regex=expression, childnodes=expression....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lines 3 through 5 are not part of the conditional ternary operator. The commas are used to declare separate variables, not related to each other. The following is valid syntax:

```
var a = 1, b = 2, c = "apples";
```

In this case, `'string' ? new RegExp(searchText, 'g') : searchText` is assigned to the first variable, `regex`. The other variables are likewise assigned their own expressions.